# Geocoding API: Daily quota exceeded, but I have a valid key and dont over use

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I pay 10.000 dollars per year for a premium GoogleMap API key. I do not do many geocodings calls at all per day. Are the syntax wrong ? The lat/lng to adress lookup works 2 out of 5 times I try, rest of the time I get message out of quota.. My GoogleKey is 100% accurate, the key is cut & pasted from https://console.developers.google.com portal.

Look at the image here.. GRRRR

[Quota exceed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtXeI.jpg)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not Google’s support

Comment: If you have a premium license, you should have support from Google.

Comment: Follow this document to file support case: https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/support#contact-support

Answer (score 0):

The "key" parameter is case-sensitive. You have it capitalized as "Key" in your request: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key#step-2-add-the-api-key-to-your-application

> When loading the Google Maps Geocoding API, substitute YOUR_API_KEY in the code below with the API key you got from the previous step.
>
> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Comment: Please include the essential parts of the link contents in your answer